# How to check whether a url has valid feeds in simplepie

Tags: php, rss, simplepie

I want to check whether a  url contains feeds or not with simplepie, before saving the root url for further purpose.

I have already tried :

```
if ($feed->error()){
//Its not working
}
```

and `validatefeed()` is of no use as it checks the url strictly.

I am using 1.3.1 version of simplepie.